# Logging Into Wells Fargo Using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to log into my bank account on Wells Fargo using Selenium Webdriver. However, I keep getting redirected to the below page whether I use Chrome, Firefox or Edge.

[image: Wells Fargo Detection Page]

I am assuming that Wells Fargo is detecting Selenium and redirecting me. My program to log in is written in Python. If anyone successfully logged into Wells Fargo using Selenium, please give me some tips regarding how you did it.

Comment: Update the question with your relevant _HTML_, _code trials_ and _error stack trace_ (if any)

Comment: can you share the URL, if it is public ?

Comment: I have the same exact problem. No code needed, except for open a slave browser by chrome `webdriver.Chrome()`, then try to login with your own username or password. It worked on a non-selenium browser, but no the ones controlled by selenium.

Comment: I also have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome

browser = Chrome()
browser.get('https://wellsfargo.com')

#GET user element and POST username to element
user = browser.find_element_by_id('userid')
user.send_keys('USERNAME')

#GET user element and POST password to element
passwd = browser.find_element_by_id('password')
passwd.send_keys('PASSWORD')
passwd.submit()
# ===> you should be logged in and redirected to account page. <=== #
```

Please tell me how it works out for you. since im not the bank client, i cannot fo beyond this point. :)