# How to login within Wells Fargo account using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, webdriverwait

I'm trying to write scripts to download relevant data from my Wells Fargo account, and using Selenium within a python script seems like a good potential solution. However, when I try to log in, I get redirected to a different login screen, which keeps redirecting to itself each time I try to log in again. How do I get past this infinite redirect?

The simplest way to reproduce this is to run this script to open a selenium Chrome browser:

```py
import selenium
browser = selenium.webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('https://www.wellsfargo.com/')
```

Then manually log in. On a normal browser this works fine. In the selenium browser, I get the redirect page.

[Someone else](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53715743/2680824) has the same problem. If there's a way to do this with Selenium I would be thrilled, but would also be happy with other methods to automate data downloads from Wells Fargo.

Comment: Try the [firefox/geckodriver](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) instead. Do you get the same issue?

Comment: I'm having an unrelated issue where I can't even open a Firefox browser with Selenium, but that's probably a topic for a different post. But the other post I referenced mentions that they tried Chrome, Firefox, and Edge and got the same results, so I'd expect the same results too.

Comment: may you investigate the difference in the header info sent when using selenium vs manually visiting?

Comment: YMMV: https://developer.wellsfargo.com/apis

Comment: @jasonm I took a quick look, and there are a couple little differences. Like in Request Headers : Accept, there's ",application/signed-exchange;v=b3" missing from the selenium one, and the Selenium Request Headers is missing "Pragma: no-cache", and there are some missing cookies in selenium

Comment: @jasonm I realized my problem with Firefox was just that it was outdated. After updating Firefox I was able to open Firefox with selenium, but I ran into the same problem I see on Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome

browser = Chrome()
browser.get('https://wellsfargo.com')

#GET user element and POST username to element
user = browser.find_element_by_id('userid')
user.send_keys('USERNAME')

#GET user element and POST password to element
passwd = browser.find_element_by_id('password')
passwd.send_keys('PASSWORD')
passwd.submit()
```

you should be logged in and redirected to account page.
Please tell me how it works out for you.
since im not the bank client, i cannot fo beyond this point. :)

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that this is almost exactly what started with. The only difference is that after sending the username and password I had `button = browser.find_element_by_id('btnSignon')` then `button.click()`.
I get the same result with your code. I can sign on to other websites, like facebook, but there appears to be something specific about Wells Fargo that makes it hard to get in with an automated browser

Answer (score 0):

So more info about after which action you *get redirected to a different login screen* would have helped us to debug your issue in a better way. However to login into your [wellsfargo](https://www.wellsfargo.com/) account you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use the following solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
  # options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get('https://www.wellsfargo.com/')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.formElement.formElementText#userid"))).send_keys("BenLindsay")
  driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input.formElement.formElementPassword#password").send_keys("BenLindsay")
  driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input#btnSignon[name='btnSignon']").click()
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: wellsfargo]

Comment: Thanks for the response! I tried this method, but it gives me the same result. If I understand correctly, the `WebDriverWait` solution assumes that the problem is clicking inhumanly fast on the submit button. In my post I mention that the problem occurs when I **manually** log in once the selenium browser boots up, which should also circumvent this problem of clicking too fast. The wait solution does appear to be the typical solution to similar problems with other websites, but it appears to me that WellsFargo is detecting the use of an automated browser and preventing login.

Comment: @BenLindsay Had it been the case of _WellsFargo is detecting_ my answer would have been different. Do you have a set of _demo credentials_ for _WellsFargo_?

Comment: you're right, in hindsight I could have been clearer. I don't know of a way to get demo credentials for wells fargo without opening a new account. Do you know of anything I'd be able to check in Google Developer Tools or something to figure out what's going on? Otherwise it might just be time for me to give up and accept either manual data downloads or whatever I can get through their APIs.

Comment: I would avoid to be tempted to open an account with _WellsFargo_ just for a single usecase. However I regularly check the _WellsFargo_ HTML DOM and there's nothing to block _WebDriver_ still now incase you follow the _best practices_.

Comment: Are you sure that any possible mechanisms to block a webdriver would show up in the HTML? Couldn't there be some backend logic that could catch a webdriver? And can you point me to which best practices you're referring to? Thanks!

Comment: has anybody found a good answer to this question? urgent please